# Gunicorn log HTTP requests made to it

Tags: django, logging, gunicorn

I am running gunicorn with the below config

```
$VIRT_ENV/gunicorn -c config.py utrade.wsgi:application \
                          --log-level=debug \
                          --timeout=0 \
                          --access-logfile=-\
                          --log-file=-
```

However it won't log HTTP requests (POST/GET) like Django would do if ran standalone. Like the ones below

```
INFO:django.server:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
INFO:django.server:"GET /login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5676
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add gunicorn.access in loggers in django `settings.py` file in the 'loggers' block.

```
LOGGING = {
  # ..
  'loggers': {
     # ..
     'gunicorn.access' : {
         'level': 'DEBUG',
         'handlers': ['console'],
         'propagate':False
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey garg, I added this to my log config in `settings.py` and it does not seem to capture request logs. Other logs from the application (from views for eg) are being logged well. 
what I could be missing?